# Which characters received power from God?

Tags: one-punch-man

If I recall correctly, Garoud, the Orochi-Psychos fusion, and Homeless Emperor received power from God. Now in the manga they apparently mentioned other characters. Are there other characters who received power from God?

Which characters received power from God?